# A divergent Feynman loop in momentum space - how to describe it in position space?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, fourier-transform, feynman-diagrams, integration

Consider the following loop diagram:

[image]

If $k$ is the incoming/outgoing momentum and we're integrating over momentum $p$, the above diagram corresponds to:
$$
- \lambda \frac{1}{k^{2} + m^{2}} \int \frac{d^{4}p}{(2\pi)^{4}} \frac{1}{p^{2}+m^{2}}
$$

This is of course divergent. If we introduce a momentum-cutoff $\Lambda$, we find that the integral in the above gives us (given in [these lecture notes](http://users.physik.fu-berlin.de/~kleinert/kleiner_reb8/psfiles/08.pdf)):
$$
\int_{\Lambda} \frac{d^{4}p}{(2\pi)^{4}} \frac{1}{p^{2}+m^{2}} \ = \ \frac{1}{16\pi^{2}} \left[ \Lambda^{2} + m^{2} \log \left( \frac{\Lambda^{2}}{m^{2}} \right) \right] + \mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{\Lambda}\right)
$$

How do I take the above and describe things in position space? I see often in literature something along the lines of "a momentum cutoff $\Lambda$ corresponds to a cutoff $\frac{\pi}{a}$, where $a$ is a cutoff seperation in position space".

Most discussion about renormalization I see focuses on momentum space, and leaves position space out of it. How can I talk about the above diagram in position space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In position space, with $x_1\to y\to x_2$, this is simply:

$$\dfrac{i\lambda}{2}\int \mathrm{d}^4y\,G_F(x_1-y)G_F(x_2-y)G_F(0)$$

with $G_F$ the usual Feynman propagator:

$$G_F(x-y)=i\int\dfrac{\mathrm{d}^4p}{(2\pi)^4}\dfrac{e^{-ip\cdot(x-y)}}{p^2-m^2+i\epsilon}$$

in momentum space, from which your expression is easily recovered.